# Как генерировать id добавляемого элемента с учетом id элементов в других таблицах?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Пишу проект на Spring Boot. У меня есть 3 сущности товаров и сущность изображения. К каждому товару  прикреплена одна фотография. Хочу хранить все фотографии в одной таблице по принципу отношения OneToOne, а id фотографии создавать такой же как и у товара, за которым она прикреплена. В итоге возник вопрос. Очевидно, что id товаров в разных таблицах формируются независимо друг от друга, поэтому их id могут быть равны, следовательно и id в таблице изображений будут одинаковые, что невозможно. Вопрос, можно ли как-то решить эту проблему или же придется делать отдельно таблицы изображений для каждой сущности товаров?

Comment: Не вижу проблемы в том, что в одном из полей может быть один и тот же id товара для разных записей. У вас таблица, допустим, ProductToPhoto, в ней 2 поля product_id и photo_id. Первичный ключ у таблицы будет состоять из двух ее полей. Таким образом, зная id-товара можно получить все изображения, или зная id-фотографии получить товары

Answer (score 0):

Либо добавьте в ключ таблицы изображений еще одно поле, которое будет говорить к какой именно из 3х сущностей относится изображение с этим ID. Либо сделайте ID у сущностей и изображений типа GUID - оно заведомо будет уникальным